# Constuct the element of Galois group of rational number

Tags: galois-theory, galois-representations

Is there a element of absolute Galois group of $\mathbb{Q}$ that is an extension of some 'easy map' like $\sigma : \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}) \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$, $\sigma(x+y\sqrt2)=x-y\sqrt2$.

What I mean is, for any algebraic extension of $\mathbb{Q}$, say $L$, and any $\mathbb{Q}$-embedding of $L$, say $\sigma$, is there a $\mathbb{Q}$-embedding  of $\mathbb{\overline{Q}}$ whose restriction to $L$ is $\sigma$?

(I know the case $L=\mathbb{Q}(i)$ and the conjugation.)

Comment: Yes, but the usual proofs involve Zorn's Lemma.

Comment: Lord Shark the Unknown // Oh, really? Thank you for the comment. Then can you recommend the reference for it? (How construct?) // Not constuct, but I want to know the method to find the image of the map for any elements.

Comment: If it requires Zorn's Lemma, then chances are you can't find the image of any elements.